# PHP array slice multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an multidimensional array but need to make it smaller.
This is an easy question I believe. I need to remove 1 array in
jsonresult array, the first one but preserve the other in the next array. I have tried array_splice but it only keeps one.

```
Array
(
[searchword] => search word
[jsonresult] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array // THIS ONE, KEEP ITS CHILDREN MOVE UP
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14889770
                    )
                   [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14389720
                    )
                   [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14869723
                    )
            )        

           [1] => Array // THIS ONE, KEEP ITS CHILDREN MOVE UP
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14889722
                    )
                   [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14389711
                    )
                   [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14869329
                    )
            )           

   )
)
```

Would like to get:

```
Array
(
[searchword] => search word
[jsonresult] => Array
    (
       [0] => Array
        (
          [id] => 14889770
        )
                   [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14389720
                    )
                   [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14869723
                    )

                   [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14889722
                    )
                   [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14389711
                    )
                   [5] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14869329
                    )
    )           

)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry have a look again, missed that..

Comment: this is what you get when you are using slice. i asked waht is your expected output that you want to come?

Comment: Please have a look again :) Cant explain it more. Thank you!

Comment: `$myArray['jsonresult'][0] = $myArray['jsonresult'][0][0];`

Comment: Just do as Mark Baker suggested.

Comment: Im so sorry :( I wasnt clear enough in my question, please if you have time have another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. This may not be the correct method but it gives what you need. (As I understand from your question)

```
//creating a sample array similar to one you given in question.
$arr_test['searchword'] = 'search word';
$arr_test['jsonresult'] = array(array(array('id'=>14889770),array('id'=>14889720)),array(array('id'=>14889780),array('id'=>14889790)));       
//creating new array
$arr_new = array();
//formatting array as you needed it
foreach($arr_test['jsonresult'] as $arr_jsonresult){
    foreach($arr_jsonresult as $jsonresult){        
        $arr_new['jsonresult'][] =  $jsonresult;        
     }
}
//overwriting the specific array key
$arr_test['jsonresult'] = $arr_new['jsonresult'];
//checking output
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr_test);
```

This code produces the following output

```
Array
(
[searchword] => search word
[jsonresult] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14889770
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14889720
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14889780
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 14889790
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Thanks! But I want it to look like: 
[jsonresult] => Array
        (
                    [0] => Array
                        ( )
                    [1] => Array
                        ( )
                    [2] => Array
                        ( )
                    [3] => Array
                        ( )
)

Comment: Oh its correct, but it gives strange output. Where some of the data in the [jsonresult] array is put above the [jsonresult] array...

Comment: Sorry it did work, something was wrong with my code!! Thank you so much! Great work really!!